# Add typescript declarations to webpack javascript library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, typescript-typings

I am currently working on a **npm package**.
This package is written in javascript and makes use of **webpack to compile/bundle**. 
I have created pure javascript packages before and simply added an **index.d.ts** file (in project root dir) for declarations. However, using webpack I cannot manage to get the declarations to be visible in a seperate project (that has the package installed).

I cannot find the resources that explain the webpack + typings + pure js, so any info in the right direction would help

**Structure**

```
/.babelrc
/package.json
/tsconfig.json
/webpack.config.json
/build
----/index.js
/src
----/index.js
----/index.d.ts
----/lib
--------/MyComponent.js
```

---

**index.d.ts**

```
declare module "my-npm-package" {
    import * as React from 'react';
    export interface WidgetHeaderProps {
        img: any;
        text: string;
    }
    let WidgetHeader: React.ComponentClass<WidgetHeaderProps>;
    export { WidgetHeader };
}
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2' 
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'commonjs react' 
  }
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-npm-package",
  "version": "0.0.17",
  "description": "Put a description here",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1"
  }
}
```